# "ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED" when using Charles Proxy

Tags: charles-proxy

I have installed Charles Proxy in windows 10, and I have did the following settings:

- installing ssl certificate
- enabling ssl proxy
- put "*" in the host and "443" in the port
- The Firewall, antivirus, and VPN are all disabled

Most sites are reachable like google, facebook, reddit. But some sites aren't reachable and show as image link below:
[This site can't be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkyrG.png).

And in Charles Proxy, the error is SSL handshake as image link below:
[image: ssl: received fatal alert: internal_error]

> Exhausted available SSL/TLS protocols, trying with everything enabled

This problem is occurred in all browser. But when using Fiddler proxy, all sites are reachable.

I have tried everything. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screen shot one can see that you are using a pretty old version of Charles proxy 3.12.3 and most likely you are also using a pretty old version of Java to run Charles proxy.

The server `www.carnival.com` Charles fails to connect to supports only TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 and the list of ciphers is restricted, too.

If you are e.g. using an outdated Java version it is reasonable that the required TLS version is not supported and/or none of the required ciphers is supported by the used Java version.

Conclusion: Al least upgrade to a newer Java version, e.g. the latest Java 8 runtime. This version supported all modern TLS versions and ciphers.

Comment: Thanks you  - I had the same problem with CHARLES PROXY 3.12.3, Windows on JAVA 1.8.x and trying to SSL-Proxy for "aida.de" .

This Answer also solved my problem.

Comment: This turned out to be a red herring for me – even though the error suggested a lack of supported ciphers in common, I had actually only installed the Charles root cert, and not and trusted it on iOS. See Settings->About->Certificate Trust Settings and ensure it's enabled.